# Change attribute during ng-repeat cycle or post cycle?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, dynamic, attributes

Let's say I have a simple directive like so:

```
app.directive('seo', function() {
    return {
        template: '<meta ng-repeat="tag in data" {{tag.attribute}}="{{tag.name}}" content="{{tag.content}}" />',
        scope : {
            data: '='
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        replace:true
    }
});
```

So all this does is create meta tags automatically by passing it some data:

HTML

```
<meta seo data="data" />
```

DATA

```
[{
    attribute : 'name',
    content : 'foo',
    name : 'image'
},
{
    attribute : 'property',
    content : 'bar',
    name : 'title'
}];
```

So the aim is to create a template that spits out something like this:

```
<meta class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="tag in data" name="image" content="foo" seo data="data">
<meta class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="tag in data" property="title" content="bar" seo data="data">
```

How can I dynamically change the attribute with Angularjs, obviously the approach I have taken by using the `{{tag.attribute}}` as the specific attribute before the equal sign does not work.

Comment: I think the best way is to use two directives. First one will do ng-repeat and pass a tag object to another. The other one will use the tag object and set attributes in `link` function. I'll try to make an example soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try two-directive approach.

First one (`seo`) will iterate with ng-repeat and in each iteration will pass current `tag` object to second one (`seo-tag`). The second one will modify element attributes according to object properties.

Example:

```
app.directive('seo', function() {
  return {
    template: '<meta ng-repeat="tag in data" seo-tag tag="tag" />',
    scope : {
      data: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true
  }
});

app.directive('seoTag', function() {
  return {
    scope : {
      tag: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        attrs.$set(attrs.$normalize(scope.tag.attribute), scope.tag.content);
    }
  }
});
```

This code is not perfect, but I think it's a good base.

This [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) can be helpful.

EDIT:

I would even skip the `seo` directive and use only `ng-repeat` with `seo-tag`. It's too complex with two levels and still the code should be quite good with simple:

```
<meta ng-repeat="tag in data" seo-tag tag="tag" />
```

in template.

Comment: Brilliant and elegant. Thankyou heaps!

Comment: Might I add a suggestion so that we don't have an isolated scope on the seoTag directive? adding `var tag = scope.$eval(attrs.seoTag);` inside the link function, and access the attribute & content from that tag. Then intead of passing `tag` through another attribute, pass it through the `seo-tag="tag"` attribute, what's your thoughts?

Comment: That's why I wrote "This code is not perfect, but I think it's a good base." :D

Comment: Nah man, great help, simple solution to a problem I've been stuck on for hours.